# Show results only on search in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my data coming in like this:

```
{
    "owner" : {
        "id" : "3f32ce2f-4300-439b-84bc-92ad46fbccf7"
    },
    "name" : "SampleProj",
    "description" : "Sample proj desc",
    "id" : "9be14f93-7c03-4391-98ad-9491594e4798",
    "status" : "OPEN"
}
{
    "owner" : {
        "id" : "3f32ce2f-4300-439b-84bc-92ad46fbccf7"
    },
    "name" : "Analysis report",
    "description" : "Analysis report",
    "id" : "dac7c5c1-5046-4437-b092-",
    "status" : "OPEN"
}
```

I am using the following to search the data and it is working fine but how do I show the results only on search(based on keyword)?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control input_search_projects" type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search Projects"/>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="list_projects_section_in_dashboard">
        <ul style="list-style: none">
            <li ng-repeat="wd in currentPageWorkOrders | filter:search">
                <a href=""> 
                    <img src="./images/projectthumb.jpg" />
                    <h4>{{wd}}</h4>
                </a>
                <p>Publisher Name</p>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question please?

Comment: Have look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584992/search-by-filter-in-angular-js).. Might help..

Comment: Sharing the custom pipe for search from the array of objects in angular 2,4,5,6 > https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xux3me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `ng-show`directive to the `ul` tag, like this:

```
<ul style="list-style: none" ng-show="search">
    <li ng-repeat="wd in currentPageWorkOrders | filter:search">
        <a href=""> 
            <img src="./images/projectthumb.jpg" />
            <h4>{{wd}}</h4>
        </a>
        <p>Publisher Name</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `ng-show` directive makes sure that the content won't be displayed until the model `search` has a non-empty string.

Comment: Search should be based on key word

Comment: @Satyadev, your filter expression in the `ng-repeat` takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of search variable inside both html tag is different, use $ctrl or vm so that scope of search for both the html tag should remain same.

Use this code, this will surely work :-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control input_search_projects" type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.search" placeholder="Search Projects"/>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="list_projects_section_in_dashboard">
        <ul style="list-style: none">
            <li ng-repeat="wd in currentPageWorkOrders | filter:$ctrl.search">
                <a href=""> 
                    <img src="./images/projectthumb.jpg" />
                    <h4>{{wd}}</h4>
                </a>
                <p>Publisher Name</p>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

`$ctrl` or `vm` signifies controller name.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sandeep mentioned, you can use `ng-show`. But I will suggest you to use `ng-if` which will not only hide the results but will prevent from rendering the contents.

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {
  $scope.currentPageWorkOrders = ['foo', 'bar'];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController" class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input class="form-control input_search_projects" type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search Projects" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="list_projects_section_in_dashboard">
      <ul style="list-style: none" ng-if="search">
        <li ng-repeat="wd in currentPageWorkOrders | filter:search">
          <a href="">
            <img src="./images/projectthumb.jpg" />
            <h4>{{wd}}</h4>
          </a>
          <p>Publisher Name</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try the above working solution of the same. Try searching `foo` or `bar`